# What's the meaning of `[`, `<-` and `->` in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

When I use the WireShark check the packages:

[image]

there have three place signs I don't understand.

1. the `[` means what? two IPs communicative to each other? but there have other IP in the range. you see the pair(`192.168.2.228 - 123.58.180.8`), there also have other IP (like `113.96.12.224`).

2.what's the meaning of `->` and `<-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[` bracket encompasses packets that belong to a single 'connection'.

While that is self-explanatory for TCP and maybe UDP, Wireshark considers ICMP echo requests/replies between two hosts also as a 'connection. Note that only the 'connection' is shown that belongs to the currently selected packet.

The → and ← are similar: they show the 'partner' packet to the currently selected one.

In your example, you've selected inbound #45 which is a reply to outbound #44, and the whole 'connection' started in #35. Note the dotted line in front of #38, #39 and #42 that don't belong to the selected connection.